# redirecting python import to another module

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on a large open source Python project, which has modules used by both the project and other projects. The goal is to move some of these modules out to a new "library" project that can then be imported by the original project and other projects.

To make this transition smooth, the thought was to copy the modules over to the new project, and have the original project then use the new import. However, to allow other project to have time to migrate later, the thought was to have the original module redirect the import.

For example, the usage is like this in repo 'neutron' (other projects could do the same):

```
cat neutron/consumer.py
from neutron.redirected import X


print(X)
```

The in the new 'neutron_lib' project created, the module looks like this (the same as what the original was in project 'neutron'):

```
cat ../neutron-lib/neutron_lib/redirected.py
X = 5
```

In the 'neutron' project, I'm trying to do this as the redirect module:

```
cat neutron/redirected.py
import neutron_lib.redirected
import sys

sys.modules['neutron.redirected'] = neutron_lib.redirected
```

When I run pylint, it gives these errors:

```
************* Module neutron.redirected
E:  1, 0: No name 'redirected' in module 'neutron_lib' (no-name-in-module)
************* Module neutron.consumer
E:  1, 0: No name 'X' in module 'neutron.redirected' (no-name-in-module)
```

If I run this, it runs fine, and consumer.py prints '5'. If I use ipython and load consumer.py, I can see 'X' in dir() output.

Any idea why I'm getting this pylint error? Is it a false error? Is there a way to override it?

Comment: The code works, but just fails pylint. Not sure how to disable the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, when running under tox, I can add the following to .pylintrc to hide the errors/warnings

```
no-name-in-module
nonstandard-exception
```

When I run pylint it passes now, as does running the Unit tests. Just wish I understood why I'm getting these errors/warnings though.